# Using Python multiprocessing Process and Queue to abort function

Tags: python, apache-spark, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function called `some_function(a,b)` which takes in two parameters a and b, and does something intensive, and then stores a Spark dataframe as an output. I want to put a timeout on some_function -> if it takes longer than 5 mins (300 seconds), I want to abort, and move to the next 'i' in the main for loop. The following method doesn't seem to work, `some_function(a,b)` appears to run forever instead of stopping after 5 mins. Maybe there's something wrong with the Queue?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def some_function(a,b):
//do some intensive process with a and b to generate spark dataframe

    //store Spark dataframe output in Q
    Q.put(some_spark_df)
    

def main(): 
    for i in range(0,10): 

            Q = Queue() 

            a = //something
            b = //something

            p = Process(target=some_function, args = (a, b))

            p.start()

            #timeout value in seconds (300s = 5min)
            p.join(300)

            #if still running after above time
            if p.is_alive():
                #terminate
                p.terminate()
                p.join()
            
            //get output from some_function(a,b)
            result_df = Q.get()
```

Comment: Your call to Q.get() is blocking. Therefore, if you terminate the subprocess before it's put something on the queue then your main function will wait *ad infinitum*. In any case, your code can't possibly work because the queue object isn't available in the subprocess's address space

Comment: The code you posted seems to be Python with JavaScript comment and there is no way that `Queue` is defined within `some_function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main process cannot successfully`join` a child process that has put data on a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance before it has taken that data off the queue. The main process will instead block indefinitely because the child process cannot terminate until the queue has been emptied.

If we can assume that the child process has essentially completed its processing when it has placed its result on the queue and therefore has either terminated or is about to terminate, then the main process can check to see if the results has been placed on the queue by doing a `get` with a *timeout* value. If it is able to retrieve the data, we know that we can safely `join` the child process. Otherwise, we call `terminate` on the child process and then we can safely `join` the child process regardless of whether   data has been put on the queue between the unsuccessful call to `Queue.get` and `Process.terminate()` (that is, there should be no race condition).

Alternatively, you *could* use instead a *managed* queue instance, which does not have the same problem as a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance as far as trying to `join` a child process that has placed data on the queue that has not been yet retrieved since the queue exits in a different process (the process created by the call to `multiprocessing.Manager()`). But the performance could suffer.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty

def some_function(queue, a, b):
    # do some intensive process with a and b to generate spark dataframe
    import time

    if a == 1:
        time.sleep(5) # to force a timeout

    # store Spark dataframe output in queue
    queue.put(a + b) # for demo purposes


def main():
    for i in range(0, 3): # three times for demo purposes

        queue = Queue()

        a = i
        b = 2

        p = Process(target=some_function, args = (queue, a, b))
        p.start()
        # timeout value in seconds (3 seconds for demo purposes)
        try:
            result_df = queue.get(timeout=3)
        except Empty:
            # child process has not completed:
            p.terminate()
            p.join()
            print('task', i, 'timed out')
        else:
            p.join() # for demo purposes
            print('task', i, 'result is', result_df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
task 0 result is 2
task 1 timed out
task 2 result is 4
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my answer and tell me why it works? You will notice that I consume queue data **after** the subprocess has been joined. Is the (mis)behaviour you describe perhaps related to the runtime platform. My code runs exactly the same whether I use a regular or managed queue. I'm using Python 3.11.4 on macOS 13.5.1

Comment: @DarkKnight See the section *Joining processes that use queues* [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=queue#multiprocessing-programming). When you call `terminate` not only is the child process killed but any threads it created, specifically the thread that a `multiprocessing.Queue` creates to send data through the `Pipe` that implements the queue. Since a `Pipe` has limited capacity, this thread is created so that it blocks rather than the main thread blocking when trying to write data to a queue. So after `terminate` is called you can now `join`.  (More...)

Comment: @DarkKnight This is why your solution more or less works: if you terminate a process that is currently writing to a queue, the queue can be corrupted. That is why your unconditional `print(q.get()` is problematic; you can't be sure what will be printed. Moreover, I think my solution is simpler.